# Which is the correct divisor when calculating an average of summed up squares

Tags: average, divisor-sum, sums-of-squares

If I have the following:

$$(1 * 1) + (2 * 2) + (3 * 3) + (4 * 4) + (5 * 5) + (6 * 6) = 91$$

Is the average $\frac{91}{6} = 15.16$ because I have $6$ distinct numbers that are being squared and then summed, or is it $\frac{91}{12} = 7.58$ because I squared and summed up $12$ numbers? I'm writing a program to calculate this. It's more about getting a for loop to work a certain way than it is about the math. The for loop increments one number at a time. I know I could put something in the comments as to how I'm coming up with this but I'm curious as to which would be more correct.

Comment: Not sure what the question is.  You can define whatever operation you want, but if you are trying to compute the average of a collection of $N$ number is you add them up and divide by $N$...doesn't matter where you got the numbers.

Comment: So in this instance I have 12 numbers so I divide by 12?

Comment: As I say I don't understand your question.  I only see six numbers, $\{1^2,2^2,3^2,4^2,5^2,6^2\}$ so if you want the average of those you divide by $6$.  If you want something else, you may have to do something different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct divisor is $6$.  To get the average, it doesn't matter how you got the terms.  Another way to get the squares is to add up the odd numbers, so you could do $\frac 16\left((1)+(1+3)+(1+3+5)+(1+3+5+7)+(1+3+5+7+9)+(1+3+5+7+9+11)\right)$  You wouldn't want the denominator to change to $21$ because you got the squares this way, would you?